# Having problems getting stop number with ROW_NUMBER () OVER - DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2, window-functions

I am trying to report on activity. I have a table that includes "stop number", but that stop number has nothing to do with the actual stop at which activity took place (stop 1 arrival/departure, stop 2 arrival/departure). So I want to number the stops using ROW_NUMBER ()...

```
    select 
WH.SEGMENT_NB,
WH.STOP_NB,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY WH.SEGMENT_NB, WH.STOP_NB ORDER BY WH.STOP_NB) as Stop,
MAX(CASE WHEN WH.WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID = 'EAA' 
    THEN WH.CREATE_TS
END) AS Actual_Arrival,
MAX(CASE WHEN WH.WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID = 'EAD' 
    THEN WH.CREATE_TS
END) AS Actual_Departure,
WH.CREATED_BY_TX AS ENTERED_BY
    from VASDW.TNT_WORK_HISTORY WH
    join VASDW.TNT_WORK_ACTION_TYPE WA on WA.WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID = WH.WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID
        and WA.RECORD_DELETE_FG = 'N'
    where WH.WORK_ACTION_TYPE_ID in('EAA','EAD')
    and wh.segment_nb = 15931846
   GROUP BY WH.SEGMENT_NB, WH.STOP_NB, WH.CREATED_BY_TX
   ORDER BY WH.SEGMENT_NB, WH.STOP_NB
```

I would expect to see this:

```
   Segment_Nb     STOP_NB     STOP
    15931846       12345       1
    15931846       12345       1
    15931846       23456       2
```

But it's reading STOP 1,2,1. Any ideas what I need to fix? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY WH.SEGMENT_NB ORDER BY WH.STOP_NB) as Stop
```

That is:

- `STOP_NB` should not belong to the partition - you want it for ordering only
- You want `DENSE_RANK()` to increment only when `STOP_NB` changes, without gaps